# How to write the Taylor expansion of the sum of several matrices?

Tags: matrix, series-expansion

When $A$ and $B$ are matrices, we have the following Taylor expansion for the inversion function together with basic information on convergence:
$$
(A+B)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}BA^{-1}+A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1}-A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1}+...,
$$
provided $Norm[A^{-1}B]<1$.
So, my question is how we can write a code in Mathematica to write this approximation up to any desired term? For example, to obtain $(I+B)^{-1}$ up to six terms by keeping the fact that matrix multiplications are not commutative ($I$ is the identity matrix).

Can we also use three matrices inside, e.g. $(I+B+C)^{-1}$ and then compute the expansion using Mathematica?

Thank you in advance for any tips or tricks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) as matrix multiplication?

Then, we can let -1 escape the noncommutative multiply

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply[H___, Times[-1, M_], T___] := - NonCommutativeMultiply[H, M, T]
```

And do the Taylor series about the `big` matrix by the `small` matrix by hand:

```
inv[n_][big_, small_] := Total@FoldList[
     #1 ** #2 &, 
     Inverse[big], 
     -(small ** Inverse[big]) & /@ Range[n]
]
```

Then, `inv[3][A, B]` gives

```
Inverse[A] - Inverse[A] ** B ** Inverse[A] + 
Inverse[A] ** B ** Inverse[A] ** B ** Inverse[A] - 
Inverse[A] ** B ** Inverse[A] ** B ** Inverse[A] ** B ** Inverse[A]
```

and `inv[3][A, B + C]` gives

```
Inverse[A] - Inverse[A] ** (B + C) ** Inverse[A] + 
Inverse[A] ** (B + C) ** Inverse[A] ** (B + C) ** Inverse[A] - 
Inverse[A] ** (B + C) ** Inverse[A] ** (B + C) ** 
Inverse[A] ** (B + C) ** Inverse[A]
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. This is really helpful and complete.

Comment: Can you extend your answer to solve this unanswered question: <http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109825/how-to-force-series-to-compute-expansions-by-considering-non-commutative-multi>

Comment: I can't get Mma to reproduce your analytic results there.  Edit: actually, maybe I can.  I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you. Please take a look. It is very similar to your above answer but with further matrix matrix multiplications. You have a better insight to this noncommutative products than me.

Comment: Evanb, have you found some time to take a look at this similar question "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109825/how-to-force-series-to-compute-expansions-by-considering-non-commutative-multi%3E"? I hope you could extend your answer for that post as well.

Answer (score 6):

Such formal power series can be computed in [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) by recursively calculating then evaluating directional derivatives. `NCDirectionalD[f,{x,h}]` calculates the directional derivative of `f` with respect to `x` in the direction `h`. The following will leverage that to produce a formal power series of `f` of degree `n` taken with respect to `x` around `x0`:

```
NCSeries[f_, {x_, x0_, n_}] := Block[{h}, 
    SetNonCommutative[h]; 
    Plus @@ (Table[1/i!, {i, 0, n}]*NestList[NCDirectionalD[#, {x, h}] &, f, n]) /. x -> x0 /. h -> x]
```

Your example is reproduced by:

```
f = inv[a + b];
NCSeries[f, {b, 0, 4}]
(* a^-1 - a^-1 ** b ** a^-1 + a^-1 ** b ** a^-1 ** b ** a^-1 - a^-1 ** b ** a^-1 ** b ** a^-1 ** b ** a^-1 + a^-1 ** b ** a^-1 ** b ** a^-1 ** b ** a^-1 ** b ** a^-1 *)
```

Your other cases are calculated similarly:

```
NCSeries[inv[1 + b], {b, 0, 6}]
NCSeries[inv[1 + b + c], {b, 0, 6}]
```

A multivariate version can be computed in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

```
dotk[ab_, k_] := Dot @@ ConstantArray[ab, k]
dotk[ab_, 0] := IdentityMatrix[Length@ab];
mInvSeries[a_, b_, n_] := Sum[(-1)^k Inverse[a].dotk[(b.Inverse[a]), k], {k, 0, n}]
```

Usage

```
a = 10 {{6, 3}, {2, 8}};
ai = mInvSeries[a, IdentityMatrix[2], 150];

(a.ai ) // N

(* {{0.981341, 0.00691085}, {0.00460723, 0.985948}} *)
```

Comment: Your answer is really nice in terms of numerical point of view. Please keep it but what I want is to obtain the expansion theoretically. I mean, we give A and B and obtain the matrix series up to 6 terms theoretically with consideration that matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: @M.J.2 Well, you can. But it is nasty: `mInvSeries[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, IdentityMatrix[2], 3]`

Comment: @M.J.2 Oh! you probably mean this `mInvSeries[IdentityMatrix[2], {{a, b}, {c, d}}, 3]`

Comment: I wish to see the result of the code exactly as in the formulation of the question, I mean in terms of $A$ and $B$. Or when the inputs are $I$ and $A$, in terms of $I$ and $A$.

Comment: @M.J.2 Mathematica has no support for that notation. $I$ is the imaginary unit ...

Answer (score 4):

In the same spirit to Dr. belisarius' answer:

```
abSeries[A_, B_, a_, n_] := Series[Inverse[A + a B], {a, 0, n}]
```

After obtaining the series you can get the matrix without the `a` by using

```
ReplaceAll[Normal[abSeries[A, B, a, n]],a->1]
```

There is definitely a way to generate the expression you quoted for "general" matrices in mathematica, but since I don't know the math in detail I don't know how to teach mathematica to derive it either. Of course programming a known expression is easy, similarly to what Dr. belisarius did.

**Addition**

This might be more akin to what was originally intended:

```
abSeries[A_, B_, n_] := Plus @@ NestList[-Dot[Inverse[A].B, #] &, Inverse[A], n]
```

It gives an expression for general expressions `A` and `B` meaning you do not have to input a literal matrix for the expressions for this to work. Of course to get the final literal result you still need to put in the matrices using `ReplaceAll` after the calculation.

If you want to use three matrices you can simply put in the addition of two matrices as `A` or `B`. i.e. `B=C+D`. You can then use `Distribute` and `Factor` to put the resulting expression into different forms.

**Example**:

```
In[1]:=ReplaceAll[abSeries[a, ee b, 5].(a + ee b), {a -> PauliMatrix[1], b -> PauliMatrix[2]}] // Simplify
Out[1]:={{1 + ee^6, 0}, {0, 1 + ee^6}}
```

Comment: what "general" expression? If `A`is the Identity, the result is a polynomial in `B`... there is no more "generality" than that AFAIK

Comment: First of all notice in the question he commented the expression is only valid if $Norm[A^{-1}B]<1$. Second, I meant more general matrices like matrices of infinite dimensionality or for some generators of a Lie algebra etc.

Comment: In general $A$ is not always Identity matrix. I believe this answer is better than the above one but this is not the expansion of the question! Because it does not keep the non-commutative property of matrix multiplications. Please choose $n=5$ and see the differences!

Comment: I totally agree with the sentence "matrices of infinite dimensionality or for some generators of a Lie algebra etc." For example, I want to finally write the Taylor expansion of $(I+B+C)^{-1}$. So, the code should take $(B+C)$ as an input and then apply the Taylor expansion two times.

Comment: @M.J.2 Please try running the following with my code `mInvSeries[A, B, 3]` Is that what you want?

Comment: Amazing. Dr. belisarius comment is totally correct. Can you now please edit your code, and write how we can simplify the procedures when there are three matrices? Thanks.

Comment: I have tested my code by multiplying the resulting matrix with the matrix `A+B`, and it gives the identity matrix up to the desired order in the expansion.

Comment: The answer of Lior Blech is good but its result is not exactly the same to the formulation in the question. I mean, it does not keep the non-commutative property of the input matrices.

Comment: I edited the answer. I'm not sure what you mean but this might answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an attempt to provide a solution for a hypothetical user that does not know the general formula beforehand and is unaware of any packages.

The answer below considers that the user is aware of the following:

- If $f$ is an expandable function that can be considered on the real line (for example $f(x)=(1+x)^{-1}$ or $f(x)=\exp(x)$), then, for a matrix variable $A$ and a real number valued variable $a$, $f(A)$=`Replace`[$f(a),a \rightarrow A$]. This point allows us to use Series for real valued variables.
- For $A$ and $B$ two matrices $\left(A.B\right)^{-1}=B^{-1}.A^{-1}$. This point is used to place the initial expression into the form $f(x)$ where $f(x)=(1+x)^{-1}$ and $ x=A^{-1}.B $

Then if we define an identity tensor for the dot product:

```
Dot[s___, id, g___] ^:= Dot[s, g]
```

The formula may be obtained with the following code that attempts to do simple replacements sequentially (`var` below is a formal wrapper that formally replaces a matrix with a real valued variable) :

```
Fold[ReplaceAll, 
Inverse[A + B] , 
{
Inverse[w_] :> Inverse[A . TensorExpand[Inverse@A . w]] ,
 Inverse[a_ . b_] :> Inverse[b] . Inverse[a],
 MatrixPower[_, 0] -> id,
 Inverse[id + s_] :> ReplaceAll[
 
                        Normal@Series[(1 + epsilon*var[s])^(-1),
                           {epsilon, 0, 3}] /. epsilon -> 1
                                  
                        , {
                             var[a_]^m_:>Dot@@ConstantArray[a,m]
                           , var->Identity
                           , 1 -> id
                          }
                        ]
}
]//TensorExpand
```

out: `(* -MatrixPower[A, -1] . B . MatrixPower[A, -1] +  MatrixPower[A, -1] . B . MatrixPower[A, -1] . B .  MatrixPower[A, -1] -  MatrixPower[A, -1] . B . MatrixPower[A, -1] . B .  MatrixPower[A, -1] . B . MatrixPower[A, -1] + MatrixPower[A, -1] *)`