# Factorize expression into matrix/vector operations if possible

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, vector, factorization

I'd like to let MMA factorize an expression (tensor) into matrix operations if that's possible.

Example – there's an expression `P1` and I want MMA to create another expression `P2` such that `P1` and `P2` are equivalent and `P2` can be expressed using matrices, vectors and operations among them;

```
F   = Array[f, {3, 3}];
Psi = 0.5*mu*(Tr[Transpose[F].F] - 3) - mu*Log[Det[F]] + 0.5*lambda*Log[Det[F]]^2;
P1  = D[Psi, {F}]; (* How to factorize P1 into matrix/vector operations? *)
```

When we take a look at `P1`, we can see that each element of `P1` is complicated fraction containing many terms.
By analyzing `P1` one could deduce equivalent notation (`P2`), which uses only operations between `mu`, `lambda` and `F` and doesn't access individual elements of `F`:

```
P2 = mu*(F - Transpose[Inverse[F]]) + lambda*Log[Det[F]]*Transpose[Inverse[F]];

(P1 - P2) // FullSimplify  (* Zero-list => P1 = P2 *)
```

**Can MMA automatically find such `P2` for me?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just wrote a package to do matrix differentiation to answer question [(138708)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141237/45431). The package can be obtained from:

https://github.com/carlwoll/MatrixD/releases.

Download the file "MatrixD-1.0.paclet" and then use:

```
PacletInstall[file]
```

to install the package. Then, load the package with:

```
<<MatrixD`
```

Using `MatrixD` I get:

```
MatrixD[.5*mu*(Tr[Transpose[F].F]-3)-mu*Log[Det[F]]+0.5*lambda*Log[Det[F]]^2,F]

(* 
0. + 1. F mu - mu Inverse[Transpose[F]] + 
1. lambda Inverse[Transpose[F]] Log[Det[F]]
*)
```