# Problem with Grad and list levels?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Assume a 2x2 matrix U and a simple vector-matrix-vector product. If I calculate the gradient of it like

```
Grad[{x,y}.U.{x,y},{x,y}]
```

mathematica returns

```
{{1,0}.U.{x,y} + {x,y}.U.{{1,0},{0,1}}, {0,1}.U.{x, y} + {x,y}.U.{{1,0},{0,1}}}
```

which doesn't make sense because of the dimensions of the arrays.
It should be

```
{{1,0}.U.{x,y} + {x,y}.U.{1,0}, {0,1}.U.{x,y} + {x,y}.U.{0,1}}}
```

Can anyone give me a hint for this unexpected result?

Comment: `Grad[]` has no way of knowing your assumption that `U` is a matrix. Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141237) already?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. You are right, I don't specify what `U` is. On the other hand, whatever assumption is used internally regarding `U`, even if none, shouldn't the second argument in the call of `Grad[]`, i.e. the list `{x,y}`, define the outer level of the result, as described in the documentation for `Grad[]`.

Comment: There is a related issue using the derivative function. The results of `D[{x, y}.U.{x, y}, {{x, y}}]` and `{D[{x, y}.U.{x, y}, x], D[{x, y}.U.{x, y}, y]}` differ.