# Calculating Matrix Derivatives

Tags: matrix, vector-calculus, mathematica-online

I'm sorry if this is an easy question, but I'm trying to refresh my memory on calculating derivatives of matrix products and have been reading the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf).  I'd like to rebuild my intuition by replicating the results in Section 2.4.1 on page 10 where the authors list some matrix derivative results.  I found this link:
[Differentiating functions of vectors/matrices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138708/differentiating-functions-of-vectors-matrices#:%7E:text=The%20matrix%20derivative%20of%20a%20matrix%20is%20not,%2F%3A%20D%20%5BX%2C%20MatrixD%2C%20NonConstants-%3E%20%7BX%7D%5D%20%3A%3D%20%24SingleEntryMatrix)
which helped some, but I think I need to get back to basics.

If I have the function:

$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}x^{T} A x + b^{T} x $

I want to calculate $\nabla f(x)$ for generic matrices $x$, $b$ and $A$.  After this I want to calculate the Hessian.

How can I do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, assuming $A$ is symmetric:

```
(* construct vectors and matrix *)
n=2;
x=Array[xc,n];
b=Array[bc,n];
A=Array[Sort[Ac[##]]&,{n,n}];

(* define function and calculate derivatives *)
f=1/2*x.A.x+b.x;
grad=Grad[f,x]//Expand
hessian=Grad[grad,x]//Expand

(* check agreement with well-known formulas *)
grad==A.x+b
hessian==A
```

See also the documentation of [`Grad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grad.html), under Examples/Applications.

Answer (score 2):

E.g.:

```
n = 3;
xs = Array[Subscript[x, #] &, n];
bs = Array[Subscript[b, #] &, {n}];
as = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {n, n}];
f[x_] = 1/2 x . as . x + bs . x;

grad = Grad[f[xs], xs]
```

[image]

```
hes = D[f[xs], {xs, 2}]
```

[image]